# Graph API for SharePoint: Update / Create ListItems with Hyperlink / Picture fields

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

How do I shape the payload to enable a post or patch for fields that are Hyperlink/Picture?

Getting those fields is straight forward: they come as "fieldName" : { "Description":"asdf", "Url":"asdf.com"}

This works in flow using the Send HTTP Request to SharePoint block, but I can't figure out how to make this work using the graph api. Do i need to set the odata type explicitly (SP.FieldUrlValue doesn't work) and what is it for Hyperlinks?

Somethink like this: {"fieldName@odata.type", "Complex" } - we use this with Collection(Edm.String) for multiple lookup fields for instance.

Kind regards,
Gregor

Answer (score 0):

Graph API does not support create this kind of column.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0

You could try to use rest api.

**Create HyperLink field:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function (){
CreateListItemWithDetails("test3")
})
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName) {
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": "test",
        'link': 
                {
                    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue' },
                    'Description': 'Google',
                        'Url': 'http://google.com'
                    },
        };



        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }




// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
</script>
```

**Update Hyperlink column:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function (){
CreateListItemWithDetails("test3")
})
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName) {
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": "test",
        'link': 
                {
                    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue' },
                    'Description': 'Google1',
                    'Url': 'http://google.com'
                },
    };



    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(41)",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
           "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}



// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, this is the same resource that is used by ms flow - which works. I don't think this works for our scenario. We're registering our client with AAD and I think we won't be able to get the sharepoint rest api going, since this requires the registration of an app in sharepoint - more lift with IT... Thanks again, Gregor